# How to execute a block of code while the app is closed in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am just asking about how an app can execute a block of code while it's closed?

For example, I want my app to suggest a plan for the user to do it everyday?

So, which framework I can use for this matter! or ...etc

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It does not really depend of Swift; It's more about iOS and UIKIt. You can't make a service which will be launched at a specific time like on Android. You can't schedule your app to be launched in the background.

What you can do is trigger local notifications, it's like push notifications, but much simpler, your application can schedule them internally, at a specific date and time, it'll be then displayed to the user, (like a push notifications) so he can launch your app or execute specific actions tied to this notification.

I invite you to look at the UserNotifications API here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications

Answer (score 0):

For sending a message to the user at some specific time, you'll need the [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/)

To perform some work in the background, then you'll have to make use of [Background Execution.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)